# Botframework-Webchat - Send activity with attachment while preventing directline from replacing the contentUrls

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have implemented a custom storage solution for the bot framework Webchat component.  In the store, I intercept `WEB_CHAT/SEND_FILES`, upload the files and get the file URLs back.  Microsoft recommends in their samples to send an event to the bot and handle it from there, however I want to dispatch a `DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY`.

The reason is that I want the activity with attachments to be visible in Webchat (to look like it was sent by the user) like it is with the default storage behaviour. Unfortunately, if I use the normal *attachments* field in an activity, the URLs are replaced by directline (just like it is mentioned [in the documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/a.upload-to-azure-storage/README.md#why-using-an-event-activity-for-uploaded-files)).

Example how it should look like:

**User message with attachment**:

[image: User message with attachment]

Is there a way to make this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way for you to get around the behavior of web chat while also trying to replicate the actions of a typical "upload" scenario. If you send a file as an upload and you have to construct the activity a certain way in order for it to show as desired, then web chat is going to respond accordingly. They only way I can think of your getting around this is to clone the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) repo, make custom changes to the code, and rebuild it for your own use.